# Changing routes when loading child components angular4

Tags: angular, angular4-router

My parent component html has some elements which I need to keep constant throughout but change my child components along with routes, so child components are loading fine but the change in routes is not getting reflected [If I try to hit the route path directly changing the address bar, it gets rendered but without parent component html elements being present]

Parent Component

```
`<parent-component>
    <child1-component></child1-component>
    <child2-component></child2-component>
    <child3-component></child3-component>

    //button for loading of child components which would be consistent 
     throughout in parent component along with child components being loaded
   <button (click)="func()"></button> 
</parent-component>`
```

parent-routing module

```
`const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'parentcomponent', component: parentComponent },
 { path: 'child1component', component: child1Component },
 { path: 'child2component', component: child2component },
 { path: 'child3component', component: child3component },
 ];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

And in my child components on successful execution of my function I do

Child component

```
`this.router.navigate[('pathofdesiredcomponent')]`
```

I tried normal routes as well as  child routes but it is not working

Comment: where are you using <router-outlet>?

Comment: @mohituprim As of now i<router-outlet></router-outlet> is only present in app.component.html, when I had use child routes then I had given in parent component as well

Comment: are you defining your main route like @NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

Comment: Yes like that , can I give a gist link or something so that u could help me

Comment: yeah sure , it would be good if you can create plunkr template

Comment: Please give me 10min i'll create and definitely update also can we move on to chat so that we can discuss I would not take much of time , then you can update the answer here , please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159913/discussion-between-enthu-and-mohit-uprim).

Comment: Anybody can please help

Answer (score 0):

Replace this.router.navigate[('pathofdesiredcomponent')] with this.router.navigate(['pathofdesiredcomponent'])

Comment: ok thanks a lot the router is working, what can be done if also I want keep the element of parent component consistent, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example?